# How to extract data with iMacros from a website whose TAG POS=x of the same element is variable between different webpages?

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I wish to extract data from a website that contains multiple webpages by searching in the website according to a list of keywords defined in a datasource .csv.

iMacros should enter sequentially in each individual page, grab certain  elements on each webpage and save data in a csv. The elements to be extracted are the same in between all webpages.

My problem is that the TAG POS=x does not remain the same for an element when moving from webpage to webpage.

> e.g on a page a HTML TAG element has `TAG POS=95 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`,
>    while on other page same HTML TAG element changes to `TAG POS=96 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT`

The only possibility I am thinking would be to pick the elements by their text attribute ( I mean their text).

### Question:

Does the  TXT parameter like `TXT:Manufacturer` (or eventually `TXT:Manufacturer*`) permits the selection without knowing the exact TAG POS=?

Is there other solution to make this kind of an extraction with iMacros?(variable position of the tag for the same html element across pages)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Generally speaking, that depends on a website which is scraped. Nevertheless you can try the command such as this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Manufacturer* EXTRACT=TXT
```

(2) If you exactly know these tag positions, the following code may be helpful as well:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
TAG POS=95 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=96 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
' other commands with extraction
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\[EXTRACT\\]|#EANF#/g, '').trim();")
```

Comment: The RegEx is a good idea. Can be applied in different scenarios.Thank you. I found another resolution though with relative positioning. I noticed a tag which has a common position and I used relative positioning with this one and a text attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tag like below. So the below tag will extract the text, that has the attribute starts with "Manufacturer" irrespective of the position.

```
TAG POS=* TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Manufacturer* EXTRACT=TXT
```